# D3.js fails to update text/numbers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a simple feedback system using Python as backend and JS/D3.js as frontend. The front-end looks like this:

[image: my simple feedback system]

Basically, I want d3.js to change the numbers every time the script updates but now it fails to do so; the numbers that first enter the DOM just stay there, and I need to refresh the browser to get the new numbers. Is there a robust and simple way to fix this? I have tried .remove but the problem with this method is that it removes the numbers every time the script runs, and I want the numbers to appear on the screen. Here's my code:

```
<script>


const inter = setInterval(function() {
                updateData();
        }, 5000); 

// ** Update data section ()
function updateData() {

  d3.dsv(",", "lagplot.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    finish: +d.FINISH,
    bib: +d.BIB,
    loype: d.COURSE,

  };
}).then(function(data) {
    d3.select("body > div > div.bib").selectAll("p")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d) { return d.bib; })

    d3.select("body > div > div.resultat").selectAll("p")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d) { return d.finish; })

    d3.select("body > div > div.loype").selectAll("p")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d) { return d.loype; })

            });
}


</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at the data join: https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3-joins

Comment: cheers. Just what I needed